# Connection to an accdb database

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a mdb database, I want to link table from an accdb database.

Here is my code :

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub AttachTable_Click()
       
       On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim NomTable As Variant, Imptable As String
    Dim NbTable As Integer, NbTableTot As Integer
    Dim CheminTableBCB As String
    Dim BaseActuel As Database, TablesLiees As TableDef, TablesLieesB, TablesLieesDATAIDS As TableDef, TablesLieesRef As TableDef
    Dim CheminData, CheminDataB, CheminRef, CheminDATAIDS As String, CheminBCB As String
    Dim ImptableBCB As String, NomTableBCB As Variant, NbTableBCB As Integer
    
    Dim Req As String
        
    'Purge des tables liées
    Call PurgeTableLiee
    
    'Purge des tables précédement crées
    Call PurgeTableCree
    
    'Récupére le chemin des tables liées
    If IsNull(Me.Chemin) Then
       MsgBox ("Veuillez saisir un chemin NadisV5")
        Me.InfosNbre = Null
        Me.Chemin.SetFocus
       Exit Sub
   Else
        CheminData = Me.Chemin & "\nadisV5.mdb"
    End If
    
    If IsNull(Me.CheminB) Then
        MsgBox ("Veuillez saisir un chemin NadisV5B")
        Me.InfosNbre = Null
        Me.CheminB.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CheminDataB = Me.CheminB & "\nadisV5B.mdb"
    End If
    
    If IsNull(Me.PathRef) Then
        MsgBox ("Veuillez saisir un chemin NadisRef")
        Me.InfosNbre = Null
        Me.PathRef.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CheminRef = Me.PathRef & "\NadisRef.mdb"
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.CheminDATAIDS) Then
        MsgBox ("Veuillez saisir un chemin pour Dat'AIDS")
        Me.InfosNbre = Null
        Me.CheminDATAIDS.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        Else
        CheminDATAIDS = Me.CheminDATAIDS & "\dataids.mdb"
    End If
```

I want to change for dataids.accdb in the last connection (Dat'AIDS).

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do not see here table attaching or linking.

Comment: It looks like linking to .accdb from .mdb is [not possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfbDm.png)

Comment: The code posted above is incomplete. Use the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778252/create-a-2003-mdb-file) post to create an .mdb format database which will open an .accdb format database with limitations like not supporting new datatypes implemented later.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041448/how-can-a-blank-ms-access-database-be-created-using-vba